# Adding field that counts occurences of feature layer using ArcPy?

Tags: python, arcpy

I have seen :

```
arcpy.Frequency_analysis(inTable, outTable, frequencyFields, summaryFields)
```

But This creates a new table with the results. I just want to add another field that will do that to an existing feature layer.

Example:

**Desired output**

For the `NTX` layer, counts each row how many times occurs in the dataset.
if SSA occurs 21 times the new column 'count' will be like this:

```
NTX
name COUNT
SSA   21
SSC   1
SDD   98
...
```

In pandas this can be:

```
df['count_']=[df['col1'].value_counts().loc[x] for x in df['col1']]
```

How to do it in ArcPy?

Comment: You should try and make your questions more clear and you will get answers. For example this one, if the feature layer has 21+1+98 rows, you cant add one column with three entries. What is your desired output?

Comment: I have updated it.I want to make a new column that will count how many times  values in the `name` column appear.The values are not 3 it is supposed to keep on and on.

Comment: So each of the 21 SSA rows will have the value 21 in a new column?

Comment: exactly. that is true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

> A Counter is a dict subclass for counting hashable objects. It is an
>   unordered collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and
>   their counts are stored as dictionary values. Counts are allowed to be
>   any integer value including zero or negative counts. The Counter class
>   is similar to bags or multisets in other languages.

Add a field for the counts and then:

```
from collections import Counter
import arcpy
fc = "my_riks" #Change
countfield = "KKOD" #Change
updatefield = "Count" #Change, field needs to be added Before executing the code

c = Counter([i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,countfield)])

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,[countfield,updatefield]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = c[row[0]]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

[image]

Comment: RuntimeError: A column was specified that does not exist.
Do you know why?

Comment: yes this is is the issue.The field must be an existing one?Because only then works. I just typed 'count' in order to make a field named count to put them and it gave error. Can't it take a new?

Comment: So I add in the code an empty field like: `arcpy.AddField_management("count")`.Is this correct?